# Any ideas why is this question getting so many views lately?

Tags: discussion, questions

[What options would Qantas Flights 7/8 have in case of emergency?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17503/what-options-would-qantas-flights-7-8-have-in-case-of-emergency)

This question got 1000 views on 15 August (13 days after being asked) and completed 2500 views 4 days later. And since then it has amassed about 900 views in one day. Any ideas, why is this getting so many views lately?

Comment: did it end up in the hot questions list?

Comment: [I don't see it in the hot questions list](http://stackexchange.com/?pagesize=50) (at least not the first 50), but the combination of `big airline name` + `flight number` + `emergency` probably attracts a good number of Google hits at the very least.